# Alias a function in a different source file

Tags: c++, c

I've got a .h file and three .cpp files. All cpp files include the .h file.
I want to create a useless function in one of the cpp files and use alias in the other cpp files to refere to this useless function. But if i move the function from important.cpp to useless.cpp it does not want to compile anymore. For some reason it doesnt see the function, even if its declared in the header.

useless.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    extern void useless(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

useless.cpp

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void useless(void) {    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

important.cpp

```
void important(void) __attribute__((alias("useless")));
```

error: 'void important()' aliased to undefined symbol 'useless'
 void important(void) **attribute**((alias("useless")));

Comment: Why can't you `#define important useless`  ?

Comment: This question is specific to a particular compiler. Probably gcc. You should make this clear in your question and in the tags. The useless function can't be defined as extern "C" function. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a bunch of `extern "C"` stuff?

If it's a C++ project and a global C++ function, you really should claim it's a C function. Doing so can lead to undefined reference-type errors, as the symbol names are different for C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is probably impossible. Take a look at gcc docs https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html  It says:

> It is an error if ‘__f’ is not defined in the same translation unit.

So if you remove `useless` from the translation unit where `important` is it looks like an error to me.